# mosquitto によるテスト通信がタイムアウトしてしまう

Tags: linux, mqtt

mosquittoを異なる二つのサーバに導入し、テスト通信したいのですが、その方法がわからない状態です。

予想では下記で通信できると思っていたのですが、タイムアウトしてしまいます。
どこが悪いのか、ご存じであればご教示お願いできますでしょうか。

**実行環境:**

- サーバA（受信側）のIP：192.0.0.1
- サーバB（送信側）のIP：192.0.0.2

※どちらもLinuxサーバ

**実行手順:**

サーバAで下記コマンドを実行（待機）

```
mosquitto_sub -d -t orz -u mqtt -P mqtt -h 192.0.0.1
```

サーバBで下記コマンドを実行（メッセージ送信）

```
mosquitto_pub -d -t orz -m "テストメッセージ送信" -u mqtt -P mqtt -h 192.0.0.1
```

Comment: -r オプションをつけても、変化はありませんでした。コメントをしていただき、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決いたしました。

AWS　EC2上で行っていたため、ポートが解放されていないことが原因でした。